# ResponseEntity skips @OneToMany list when returning the entity in body

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

Why doesn't my endpoint return the list of players when returning Clubs?
I would expect to have all the properties, including the list of players, but the `ResponseEntity` seems to be skipping it, look, the response I'm getting now:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "club1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "club2"
    }
]
```

My `Club` class:

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
public class Club {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "club", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<Player> players;


}
```

My query:

```
@Query("Select clubs from Club clubs left join fetch clubs.players")
List<Club> getAllClubsWithPlayers();
```

and finally the controller:

```
@GetMapping("/api/clubs/withPlayers")
ResponseEntity<List<Club>> getAllClubsWithPlayers() {
  List<Club> clubsList = clubInterface.getAllClubsWithPlayers();
  return ResponseEntity.ok().body(clubsList);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the player class?

Comment: Why did you put @JsonBackReference on the players mapping? You might want to look into what those annotations mean, but it appears Jackson excludes them from serialization to JSON, and only includes the managed side. My understanding was you'll get an exception when it tries to convert JSON in to your entity as it doesn't allow JsonBackReference  to be used on a collection - see https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion#bd-managed-back-reference